# Spring Social Insufficient permission for this operation (LinkedIn)

Tags: spring, linkedin-api, spring-social, spring-social-linkedin

I am trying to do a simple search using spring social in linkedin. I have built everything needed to get to the linkedin server, but now I get an exception with the search. Here is my code:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.social.linkedin.connect.LinkedInServiceProvider">
        <constructor-arg value="75........" /> // Api Token
        <constructor-arg value="Fl2........" /> //secret
</bean>
```

I use it like this

```
@Autowired LinkedInServiceProvider provider;

  .........
LinkedIn ln = provider.getApi("AQW......."); //My accessToken
        SearchParameters searchParameters = new SearchParameters();
        searchParameters.setFirstName("firsname");
        searchParameters.setLastName("lastname");
ln.profileOperations().search(searchParameters);
```

I know I may need to give this app access to my profile, but I am not sure how. I thought it would have it since I am the developer already.

If I go to the app in the linkedin website, I can see that my requests went through and they look fine, but in my java application I get the following exception:

```
2016-04-07 14:01:47,059 [ERROR] [io.undertow.request] (default task-8) UT005023: Exception handling request to /springsocial/home: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.social.InsufficientPermissionException: Insufficient permission for this operation.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:980) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at controllers.HeadRequestsFilter.doFilter(HeadRequestsFilter.java:60) [classes:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: org.springframework.social.InsufficientPermissionException: Insufficient permission for this operation.
    at org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.impl.LinkedInErrorHandler.handleError(LinkedInErrorHandler.java:49) [spring-social-linkedin-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:572) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:280) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.impl.ProfileTemplate.search(ProfileTemplate.java:112) [spring-social-linkedin-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at controllers.Entry.home2(Entry.java:59) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 36 more
```

My application is set to have all permissions as in the photo:

[image]

When I authenticate, it asks for there permissions:

[image]

And when I go to the application activity in Linkedin, I see requests coming and handeled, but I get that error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your application permissions. The error you are getting clearly states that the application does not have enough permissions to make the search. You can set your application permissions in the  [application configuration](https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer).

Comment: My application have all permission. I updated with a photo, can you please take a look and let me know if this is not what you mean?